# Wercker Services Not Being Linked to Main Container

Tags: docker, wercker

The issue I am experiencing with *Wercker* is that the specific [linked services](http://devcenter.wercker.com/docs/services/linking-services.html) in my wercker.yml are not being linked to my main docker container.

I noticed this issue when my node app was not running on port 3001 after a successful *Wercker* deploy in which it's output can be seen in the image below.

[image]

Therefore I SSH'd into my server and into my docker container that was running after the Wercker deploy using:

```
docker exec -i -t <my-container-name> ./bin/bash
```

and found the following *MongoDB* error in my *PM2 logs*:

```
[MongoError: connect EHOSTUNREACH 172.17.0.7:27017
```

The strange fact is that from the images below you can see that both the environment variables that I need from each respective service have been set:

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know why the services containers cannot be accessed from my main container even thought their environment variables have been set?

The folloing is the wercker.yml file that I am using.

```
box: node

services:
  - id: mongo
  - id: redis

build:
  steps:
    - npm-install

deploy:
  steps:
    - npm-install
    - script:
        name: install pm2
        code: npm install pm2 -g
    - internal/docker-push:
        username: $DOCKER_USERNAME
        password: $DOCKER_PASSWORD
        repository: /
        ports: "3001"
        cmd: /bin/bash -c "cd /pipeline/source && pm2 start processes_prod.json --no-daemon"
        env: "MONGO_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR"=$MONGO_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR,"REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR"=$REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR
    - add-ssh-key:
        keyname: DIGITAL_OCEAN_KEY
    - add-to-known_hosts:
        hostname: 
    - script:
        name: pull latest image
        code: ssh root@ docker pull /:latest
    - script:
        name: stop running container
        code: ssh root@ docker stop  || echo ‘failed to stop running container’
    - script:
        name: remove stopped container
        code: ssh root@ docker rm  || echo ‘failed to remove stopped container’
    - script:
        name: remove image behind stopped container
        code: ssh root@ docker rmi /:current || echo ‘failed to remove image behind stopped container’
    - script:
        name: tag newly pulled image
        code: ssh root@ docker tag /:latest /:current
    - script:
        name: run new container
        code: ssh root@ docker run -d -p 8080:3001 --name  /:current
    - script:
        name: env
        code: env
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the Wercker services are available only in the build process, and not the deploy one. Mongo and Redis are persisted data stores - meaning they are not supposed to be reinstalled every time you deploy.
So make sure you manually setup Redis and Mongo in your deploy environment.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing exactly that and it worked perfectly.